# Creating a 3D lattice with periodic boundaries - create every combination of (x,y,z)

Tags: python

I am trying to create a program that puts identical non-overlapping particles of diameter d in a cubic (3d) lattice with periodic boundary conditions.

Really what this means is I need a program that creates an XYZ file that will look something like the below but will go through every comibination:

```
H 0.0000000.0000005.000000
H 0.0000000.0000006.000000
H 0.0000000.0000007.000000
H 0.0000000.0000008.000000
H 0.0000000.0000009.000000
```

Now for some reason, my code below is keeping my z value 0 and not going through the values to create the the other combinations ...instead its only going through x and y.

```
#create a file and enter first two lines
text_file=open("question1.xyz","w")
text_file.write("\n")
text_file.write("comment goes here\n")

L=10
d=1

#first particle or line will be at 0,0,0, counter used to count how many lines
x,y,z = 0,0,0
counter=0

#placing the particles
while x<=L-d:
    while y<=L-d:
        while z<=L-d:
            text_file.write('H ')
            text_file.write('%f'%x)
            text_file.write('%f'%y)
            text_file.write('%f\n'%z)
            counter=counter+1
            z=z+d
        z=0
        y=y+d
    z,y=0,0
    x=x+d

text_file.close()

with open("question1.xyz") as infile:
    with open("outputfile.xyz","w") as outfile:
        for i,line in enumerate(infile):
            if i==0:
                outfile.write('%f\n'%counter)
            else:
                outfile.write(line)
```

Any ideas on why its happening? My while statement is a little messy but i am not sure how else to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an easier way. Use [itertools.product](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
import itertools

L = 3
d = 1
counter = 0
with open("question1.xyz","w") as text_file:
    text_file.write("\ncomment goes here\n")
    for x,y,z in itertools.product(range(L),repeat = 3):
        text_file.write('H %f %f %f\n' % (x, y, z))
        counter=counter+1
```

Comment: But just for my own knowledge, do you have any idea why my way of doing it doesnt produce  any z valueS?

Comment: Your code does work -- `x`, `y` and `z` are iterating through all the values. I think it is just that there is no space printed between the three numbers.

Comment: Do you know how I would create spaces between my valueS?ive tried every combination of ad ding spaces in the text_file.write area of the code

Comment: I had to go back with my old code because I didnt mention in the question but I need to take into consideration the diameter (d) of the molecule. Your above code assumes 1

Comment: any idea on how I can incorporate your code while taking into consideration d?

Comment: Where does the diameter information come from? a list or a function? Please give an example showing how it corresponds to x, y, z values.